# References in English about Dirichlet's condition, $\Delta$ and $\nabla$

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Page 809 [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.1020/materiaali/Mat-1_1020_juhani_pitkaranta__tkk_n_laaja_matematiikka_ii__2007_.pdf?state%3aCourseAdditionalMaterial=BrO0ABXcgAAAAAgAAGWVkaXRVc2VyV2FudHNUb0NoYW5nZUZpbGVzcgARamF2YS5sYW5nLkJvb2xlYW7NIHKA1Zz67gIAAVoABXZhbHVleHAAdxMAABBlZGl0RGlhbG9nSGlkZGVuc3EAfgAAAQ%3D%3D) shows Dirichlet's condition:

$$\begin{cases}
-\nabla u = \rho & \text{when }A\text{ is an inner point} \\
u=0 & \text{when on the border of } \partial A \\
\end{cases}$$

and there are certain extremely vague statements such as the top of the page 809 or I just cannot make head-or-tail of the language.

**I am trying to translate the page 809 here to English (may contain mistakes)**

> If vector field $\bar{F}$ with source $\rho$ is known and we know that
>   $F$ is gravitation field, so some potential $u$ exists so that
>   $\bar{F}=-\nabla u$ (so it is with electricity field and gravitation
>   field), so field and source relationship is $\bar{F}=\rho$ that can be
>   written as
>
> $$\Delta u=\rho,     \tag{1}$$
>
> so called *Poisson equation*. Points where $\bar{F}$ is sourceless,
>   i.e. $\nabla \cdot \bar{F}=0$ are satisfied with the *Laplace
>   equation*
>
> $$\Delta u=0,$$
>
> also known as harmonic.
>
> The Laplace and Poisson equations are commonly in boundary value
>   problems, where we consider open set $A$ or as-usually-said
>   *area* $A$ ($A\subset\mathbb R^2$ or $A\subset\mathbb R^3$) --
>   and in the boundary some border condition. -- For example, the 
>   boundary condition can be so-called (homogeneous) *Dirichlet's
>   condition*, so we get
>
> $$\begin{cases}
>  -\nabla u = \rho & \text{when }A\text{ is an inner point} \\ u=0 & \text{when on the border of } \partial A \\ \end{cases}$$
>
> This can be shown with certain rules -- [cannot understand this part].
>   Usually this kind of situations are solved numerically.

**Reflecting**

Now, it is extremely hard to see what is the main message here. If I can understand right, there are something called boundary-value problems that and Dirichlet/Laplace equations may be typical examples of them, somehow with physical restrictions. The part $(1)$ is something I cannot understand at all. It means $\Delta u = \rho=\bar{F}=-\nabla u$ so $\Delta u=-\nabla u$. Sorry but is there any sense with $\Delta u=-\nabla u$? I am gasping here sorry, no way -- something is here skewed -- could someone explain? Please, contain references so I could find some peer-reviewed material in English to compare things, perhaps understanding this better.

Comment: The equation in the reference is **not** $\bar F=\rho$, it is $\nabla \bar F=\rho$.

Comment: This http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator may also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If vector field $\bar{F}$ with source $\rho$ is known and we know that
$F$ is a gravitational field, so some potential $u$ exists so that
$\bar{F}=-\nabla u$ (as it is with electricity fields and gravitation
fields), so field and source relationship is $\nabla \cdot \bar{F}=\rho$ that can be
written as

$$\Delta u= -\rho,     $$

the so called *Poisson equation*. Points where $\bar{F}$ is sourceless,
i.e. $\nabla \cdot \bar{F}=0,$ satisfy the *Laplace
equation*

$$\Delta u=0,$$

in which case $u$ is  known as harmonic.

The Laplace and Poisson equations are commonly encountered  in boundary value
problems, where we consider open set $A$ or as-usually-said
*domain* $A$ ($A\subset\mathbf R^2$ or $A\subset\mathbf R^3$) --
and in the border $\partial A$ some boundary condition holds. -- For example, the 
boundary condition can be the so-called (homogeneous) *Dirichlet's
condition*, where we have

$$ -\Delta u = \rho  \; \; \mbox{when at an interior point} $$
$$  u=0  \; \; \mbox{when on the boundary } \partial A $$

This problem has a unique solution under fairly mild restrictions,such as when $\rho$ is bounded, locally Hölder continuous on $A,$ and
every point of $\partial A$ is regular with respect to the Laplacian. A simple sufficient condition for regularity of $A$ is that an exterior sphere condition holds at each point of $\partial A.$

NOTE: I added the last bit out of *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order* by Gilbarg and Trudinger. Vector fields that can be written as the gradient of some function are called "conservative" fields. In $\mathbb R^3,$ the first thing to check is that the curl of a field is zero, in which case it is (locally) the gradient of a function.